# libgdx scene2d add multi table

Tags: java, libgdx, scene2d

I am try to get this [table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GKxfg.png) on bottom screen.
First I added two table on root table. Every Table has four cells.
 this is my code. How can do this. This code not work.

```
    Table table = new Table();        
    table.bottom();
    table.setFillParent(true);

    Table table1 = new Table();
    table1.setFillParent(true);

    Table table2 = new Table();
    table2.setFillParent(true);
            .
            .
            .

    table2.add(image1).size(image1.getWidth(), image1.getHeight());
    table3.add(image2).size(image2.getWidth(), image2.getHeight());
    table3.add(image3).size(image3.getWidth(), image3.getHeight());
    table3.add(image4).size(image4.getWidth(), image4.getHeight());
    table3.add(image5).size(image5.getWidth(), image5.getHeight());
    table2.add(table3);
    table2.row();
    table2.add(image6).size(image6.getWidth(), image6.getHeight());
    table2.add(image7).size(image7.getWidth(), image7.getHeight());
    table2.add(image8).size(image8.getWidth(), image8.getHeight());
    table2.add();
    table1.add(table2);
    table.add(table1).expandX();

    table5.add(image9).size(image9.getWidth(), image9.getHeight());
    table6.add(image10).size(image10.getWidth(), image10.getHeight());
    table6.add(image11).size(image11.getWidth(), image11.getHeight());
    table6.add(image12).size(image12.getWidth(), image12.getHeight());
    table6.add(image13).size(image13.getWidth(), image13.getHeight());
    table5.add(table6);
    table5.row();
    table5.add(image6).size(image6.getWidth(), image6.getHeight());
    table5.add(image7).size(image7.getWidth(), image7.getHeight());
    table5.add(image8).size(image8.getWidth(), image8.getHeight());
    table5.add();
    table4.add(table5);
    table.add(table4).expandX();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each of the two root tables, I would make it a 4x2 table, where the very first cell spans three columns, and the second cell contains one inner table for the four cells.

I would also use helper methods where possible to cut down on redundancy to make it easier to tweak. Try starting with this (untested):

```
private static Cell addSizedImage(Table table, Image image){
    return table.add(image).size(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());
}

private static Table generateBlock (Image... imgs){
    if (imgs.length != 8) throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Must have 8 images");
    Table root = new Table();
    addSizedImage(root, imgs[0]).colspan(3);

    Table innerTable = new Table();
    addSizedImage(innerTable, imgs[1]);
    addSizedImage(innerTable, imgs[2]).row();
    addSizedImage(innerTable, imgs[3]);
    addSizedImage(innerTable, imgs[4]);

    root.add(innerTable).row();

    addSizedImage(root, imgs[5]);
    addSizedImage(root, imgs[6]);
    addSizedImage(root, imgs[7]);

    return root;
}

private Table createImagesUI (){
    Table root = new Table();
    root.setFillParent(true);
    root.bottom();

    root.add(generateBlock(image1, image2, image3, image4, image5, image6, image7, image8)).expandX();
    root.add(generateBlock(image9, image10, image11, image12, image13, image14, image15, image16)).expandX();

    return root;
}
```